# Is an ActiveRecord object in a query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Is this more concise way of writing this:

```
current_user.products.where(:product_id => product.id).present?
```

Does rails have something like?

```
current_user.products.has? product
```

I know I can do:

```
current_user.products.include? product
```

... but that loads all the products. I'm trying to get a smart query out of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `exists?` method. Like:

```
current_user.products.exists?(product.id)
```

Might have a look at the [Active Record Query Interface Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#existence-of-objects) and the [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-exists-3F).